# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer C#

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой объявления константы:

```
Form1 asx = new Form1();
const string valid = "";
if (asx.method_two.Checked) {
    valid = "1234567890";
} else {
    valid = "ADCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так Вы же пытаетесь изменить константу. Константу можно только один раз присвоить(при инициализации) и потом её менять нельзя.
Зачем Вам вообще нужна константа? Уберите `const` и проблем не будет, тем более, что у Вас по логике вещей переменная, а не константа.

P.S. И больше никогда не выкладывайте код картинкой.

Comment: Спасибо большое, просто голова болит от ночного коддинга(

Comment: @GrapeKun, если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, пометьте его как верный, нажав на галочку рядом с ответом.